# How to create this banner? Stretching something 100 and bottomed between left and right aligned stuff

Tags: html, css

Here is the design:

```
IMG                                     SEARCH FIELD (floated right)
IMG
IMG I want here something to be 100% stretcheeeeeeeeeddddddddddddddd
```

http://jsfiddle.net/478AC/

```
<img src="http://static.idokep.hu/images/nagyelore/ujikon2/041.png" style="float: left">
    <div style="float: right; background-color: yellow;">Search field</div>
    <div style="background-color: red; float: left">left it be 100% width AND alligned to bottom</div>
```

f

Comment: not clear.can you add an image of what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/478AC/1/)**

**The Code Change:**

```
<div style="background-color: #FF0000;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;">left it be 100% width AND alligned to bottom</div>
```

If you want it to be in between the cloud and yellow field, use the below.

**[WORKING DEMO - 2](http://jsfiddle.net/478AC/2/)**

**The Code Change:**

```
<div style="background-color: #FF0000;
    bottom: 125px;
    left: 205px;
    position: absolute;">left it be 100% width AND alligned to bottom</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, the "left it be 100% width AND alligned to bottom" must be in between the cloud and yellow field :)

Comment: Yes. Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/478AC/2/ - @JohnSmith Edited the same in the answer above.